# Show that $f(x, y)=(-1)^y x$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{R}^*$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Show that $f(x, y)=(-1)^y x$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ to $\mathbb{R}^*$.
(REMARK: To combine elements of $\mathbb{R}^{+}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, one multiplies first components, adds second components.) Conclude that $\mathbb{R}^* \cong \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb {Z}_2$.

I am stuck how to prove that the function is a bijection.

I can show it is a surjection. Showing that it is an injection gives me an equation of $x$ and $y$. I think fact that $y$ only takes the values of 0 and 1 is essential here.

Should I start with $y_1=y_2=0$ then 1 then show that $x_1$ = $x_2$ ?

Comment: To show it's injective just note that one would need the kernel to be trivial.  So, show that something in the kernel is the identity, which would be $(1,0)$.  We have that $(-1)^y x = 1$ provided that $|x| = 1$.  Since $x \geq 0$ we have that $x = 1$.  And, then $y = 0 \mod 2$ follows from analyzing $(-1)^y = 1$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a homomorphism due to index rules.

You have shown it's surjective.

Suppose $f(a,b)=f(x,y)$. Then $(-1)^ba=(-1)^yx$. Then, since $a,x>0$, $a=x$. It follows that $b=y$ since $b,y\in\{0,1\}$ (which is how I presume you conceptualise $\Bbb Z_2$). Thus $(a,b)=(x,y)$. Thus $f$ is injective.